# How do I get the sponge?

Tags: candy-box-2

I jump into the sea a lot and get to the sea snake but I haven't gotten the sponge yet to squeeze, can anyone help me?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @JeffreyLin - One person probably downvoted (for whatever reason), and then the hive mentality jumped on the bandwagon

Answer (score 3):

You get it by killing the sponge on the sea floor. With the sponge you are able to squeeze into smaller gaps (such as the gap in The Hole to reach a chest).

Comment: Actually, you DO get it by killing something - you kill the sponge itself.

Comment: @LukeZaz Edited, thanks. I guess I wasn't looking that much when I went into the ocean :3

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get the sea sponge:

1. Go to the port and into the sea.
2. Keep on killing enemies but STAY AT THE BOTTOM OF THE SEA FLOOR.
3. When you see an item that looks like the shell powder, but with more symbols, kill it.
4. Go into your inventory and you should have the sea sponge!

END

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to wear the octopus crown with jaspers, the pink enchanted gloves, any weapon (preferably your best one), and stay close to the floor of the sea. You won't always get it first time round, so go a few times till you do.